# Binding ComboBox item to string

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to bind a ComboBox item to a string, but it does not work. My code is below.

Code in view:

```
<ComboBox          
 SelectedValuePath="content" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding ProductName}" 
            ......                       
 <ComboBoxItem>1111111111</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>2222222222222</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>333333333333</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code in view model:

```
private string _productName;
public string ProductName
{
    get { return _productName; }
    set
    {
        if (_productName != value)
        {
            _productName = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ProductName");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code works just fine, you didn't forget to set the DataContext, did you?

Comment: Yes I did set up DataContext. The string to string binding works fine, but this Combobox binding does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to get the text from the ComboboxItem and not the ComboBoxItem iteself.

So you are binding the wrong information. This should work.

```
<ComboBox          
SelectedValuePath="content" 
Text="{Binding ProductName}" 
            ......                       
<ComboBoxItem>1111111111</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>2222222222222</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>333333333333</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Selected Item is of type ComboBoxItem, it will not accept String.
If you want to display product name in some other place try maybe something like this:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=my_ComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion.
You already use a binding for the `SelectedItem`, why don't you set up another binding for the Items using the `ItemsSource`? So you would not need to add them statically in your view.

In addition you would not have the trouble to wonder whether you deal with instances of `ComboxItem` or `String` with your `SelectedItem` binding.
In case of the binding via `ItemsSource` you can be sure that the `SelectedItem` is a string.

Here is the code:

```
<ComboBox          
 SelectedValuePath="content" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding ProductName}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding ProductNames}"
</ComboBox>
```

In your view model (or code behind) you define the `ProductNames`:

```
public String[] ProductNames
{
    get
    {
        return _productNames;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_productNames!= value)
        {
            _productNames = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ProductNames");
        }
    }
}
String[] _productNames;


public NameOfConstructor()
{
    List<String> productNames = new List<String>();
    productNames.Add("A");
    productNames.Add("B");
    productNames.Add("C");

    ProductNames = productNames.ToArray();
}
```

If it was possible that the list of names changes during execution, I would use a `ObservableCollection<string>` instead `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

1. Create an observable collection of Product in View Model. Lets Say ProductCollection
2. Bind to the ComboBox ItemSource as given below

> ```
> <ComboBox  Name="productComboBox"  Width="200" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}">
>                 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
>                     <DataTemplate>
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"></TextBlock>
>                     </DataTemplate>
>                 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
>             </ComboBox>
> ```

if you want to show in textbox somewhere 
use this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=productComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```